# Solve, $\cos(x)=\frac 25, \frac{3\pi}{2}<x<2\pi$ and $\sin(y)= \frac35, \frac\pi2<y<\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A. Draw and label two triangles, one containing angles $x$ and one
containing angle $y$. (can use the $x-y$ axis version of triangles)

B. List $\sin(x), \cos(x), \sin(y)$, and $\cos(y)$

c. Find $\sin(x+y)$

d. Find $\sin(2x)$

e. Find $\cos(\frac y2)$

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have done!

Comment: I don't even know where to start, to be fully honest

Comment: I need help, I am so lost and I do apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

To obtain $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(x)$ use the basic trigonometric inequality:

$$\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$$

But note that $x$ is in the fourth quadrant, while $y$ is in the second. What does that say about the sign?

For the three calculation they are just basic trigonometric identities. You can find a load of them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) and also you can find the identities you need.

HINT 2:

For problem A. Use the fact that cosine is an even function. Because $x$ is in the fourth quadrant we can write $x = 360^{\circ} - \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is an obtuse angle so we have:

$$\cos (x) = \cos(360^{\circ} - \alpha) = \cos (- \alpha) = \cos {\alpha}$$

Now since $\cos (x) = \frac{adjacent}{hypothenuse}$, we can easy draw a right triangle with side 2 and hypothenuse 5. From this you obtain $\alpha$ and subsequently $x$.

Note that $x > \pi$, so a triangle with angle $x$ would be impossible to construct, because the sum of the interior angles in a triangle is $\pi$.

For sine use the fact that $\sin (\pi - \alpha) = \sin {\alpha}$ and $sin x = \frac{opposite}{hypothenuse}$

Comment: I got everything except for question "a"

Comment: I've posted a Hint fo question A, as usually I left some gaps fo you to fill them.